# sas code_pick the column right after changes one

Tags: sas

This is the table I have, I need to pick if person is same, and code should be "CA", street line should be change for the next column. It goes WC-WC-EC, SO I need to pick EC column. So i put star on them which columns supposed to be pick.

```
 person code date    street_line;
 2     CA    11JAN10  wc ;
 2    CA     10JAN10  WC;
**2   CA     10JAN10  EC** ;
 2    MA     3jan10   TM;
 3    CA     20FEB07  EC ;
 3    CA     20FEB07  EC;
**3   CA     24MAR09  WP;**
 4    CA     2JUN08   WP;
 4    CA     12JUN08  WP;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FIRST and NOTSORTED, you can identify changes in variables.  In this case, we identify a change in street_line (`first.street_line`) when no change in person or code occurs (`not first.code`).  Changes always down-propagate, so a change in person would also be a change in code and street_line, hence needing to check.

```
data want;
set have;
by person code street_line notsorted;
if first.street_line and not first.code then flag=1;
run;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly the "CA" part, so if that needs to specifically be "CA" and not just a same-value for code, add that to the `if` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lag()` function to get the value from the previous row.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by person ;
  lag_Street = lag(street_line) ;

  if not first.person and code = 'CA' and street_line ^= lag_Street then output ;
run ;
```

If it's the first record per `person`, it's not possible to determine if the value of `street` has changed, as there's no previous value for that `person`.

So, `not first.person` selects only the 2nd record per `person` onwards, you state the `code = 'CA'` must be true, and `street_line ^= lag_Street` checks to see if the `street_line` value differs to the previous row.

Comment: @ChrisJ - Answers should contain some explanation of what they're doing, not solely code, to be good answers on this site.  Please add some explanation of what you're doing here so others can understand it.  Thanks!

Comment: Edited to explain logic.

Comment: Thanks, that improves it.  I would note that lag() does not actually get the value from the previous row, but _stores_ the value from the previous row in a queue.

Comment: ...and that's why I don't like the lag() function. It's easily misunderstood and misused, and any bugs are likely to go unnoticed.  IMO using `retain` is a better choice in most situations.